# What is the best way to cast each item in a LINQ to Entities query to an interface?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities, iqueryable

I have an entity object 'User' which implements 'IUser':

```
IQueryable<User> users = Db.User;
return users;
```

But what I actually want to return is:

```
IQueryable<IUser>
```

So what is the best way to convert

```
IQueryable<User>
```

to

```
IQueryable<IUser>
```

without actually running the query? Right now I am doing this but it seems like a hack:

```
IQueryable<IUser> users = Db.User.Select<User, IUser>(u => u);
```

Comment: Craig Stuntz is correct: L2E doesn't support the Cast method. If fails with: "Unable to cast the type 'MyType' to type 'MySubTypet'. LINQ to Entities only supports casting Entity Data Model primitive types.". I deleted my answer since it didn't provide any value.

Comment: Doesn't this eager load the results? it doesn't get the whole table when for each part of the query?

Comment: Which .NET version? In .NET 4 you should be able to assign any IQueryable<User> to a variable of type IQueryable<IUser> without the need for a cast of all the entries is the list...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your "hacky" solution looks fine to me.

Comment: I just tried that with the following exception:

The 'TypeAs' expression with an input of type 'Bla.User' and a check of type 'Bla.IUser' is not supported. Only entity types and complex types are supported in LINQ to Entities queries.

Comment: Thanks for the speedy responses Craig!