# Can you program against interfaces in EF if you do NOT make use of navigation properties?

Tags: linq-to-entities

Based on this question ( [error when using interfaces for Entity Framework (4.2) entities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8747442/error-when-using-interfaces-for-entity-framework-4-2-entities))

I'm trying to achieve persistence ignorance for read-only operations in the other layers of the application.

Using a [very simple select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1240087/what-is-the-best-way-to-cast-each-item-in-a-linq-to-entities-query-to-in-interfa) these 3 work

```
var test = _newsSource.GetAll().ToArray();
var test2 = _newsSource.GetAll().Where(n => n.NewsID>0).ToArray();
var test3 = _newsSource.Find(n => n.ExpiryDate.HasValue).ToArray();
```

but a query following that involving joins fails.
i've gone as far as using an [interceptor](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alexj/archive/2010/03/01/tip-55-how-to-extend-an-iqueryable-by-wrapping-it.aspx) to rewrite the expressions without any references to the interfaces. Then using The [TypeChangeVisitor](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9120931/57883) from another SO answer.

I also tried working [VisitUnary](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9120931/57883) to strip away unncessary cast/converts

This approach is failing on the simple tests saying my only variable is not bound.

Comment: The question isn't every clear.  I assume your GetAll() is reutnring an IQueryable<T>.  Can you post your attempting Join that is failing?  There is nothing about simply joining some data that should require any of the complex things you've already tried.